# Convert a string into Date in a query to get data between two dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

collection data:

```
{
    "UserId":ObjectId('55525252525252'),
     "CreatedDate":"Fri Apr 01 2015"
},
{
    "UserId":ObjectId('55525252525252'),
     "CreatedDate":"Fri Apr 01 2016"
},
{
    "UserId":ObjectId('55525252525252'),
     "CreatedDate":"Fri Apr 01 2017"
}


db.getDate.find({"UserID":ObjectId('55525252525252'),"CreatedDate":{"$gte":new Date('Fri Apr 01 2015'),"$lte":new Date('Fri Apr 01 2017')}})
```

- when I execute this country it not returning data as expected
- How to convert string into date to perform the give query

Comment: Is storing date as date type not a option for you ?

Comment: I don't have an option to change **CreatedDate** as date. it is saving as a string

Comment: Do you have control over string format ? If you can save date in ISO 8601 like YYYY-MM-DD format your queries will work as expected.

Comment: so, my query is not gonna work if **CreatedDate** saved as a string?

Comment: I don't see any straightforward way to make it work in the string format you have. Either store in ISO-8601 string format or date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store date in [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) format, you can convert your existing `CreatedDate` field using :

```
db.getDate.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.CreatedDate = new Date(doc.CreatedDate);
    db.getDate.save(doc);
});
```

In your query build [`Date()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) with `new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")`

```
db.getDate.find({
    "CreatedDate": {
        "$gte": new Date('2015-04-01'),
        "$lte": new Date('2017-04-01')
    }
})
```